# Adding Content from MySQL Database to Fill a Page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to fill a page with content from a database. My thinking is, to use some kind of while loop in php and go through each row in the database and use jQuery's .prepend command to add it below the other content.

The problem I'm seeing in this, is that every time the page is loaded it would be pretty resource intensive to have to load through every row in a table and display it.

I was thinking that when I display the item I should then change a value in the table that indicates that it is already displayed and therefore keep the current content. My problem with this is, how exactly would I keep this content there if it's dynamically added like this?

Or is there just a better way in general to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with just echo'ing the content with php? Also, is there only user for this app? If no, you'll need to add a flag for every user for every piece of content.

Comment: @ChrisHenry it's basically meant to just draw from a table row by row and show that table on the page in a reverse order (latest entries first), which essentially will be displayed in a table form.

Comment: Can you explain your program logic? Do you have a PHP page that you call using ajax from your page parse the results and send them to the screen using JQuery? If so the page could save lastID received in javascript and make the next call using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of which entry #s you've already stored and deal with the new stuff using sql's limit function.

Comment: Better to use jQuery or PHP for this?

Comment: Well, you want this to be dynamic, right? Therefore you have to use javascript to keep track of which entries you're going through and then use some ajax (through the jQuery framework) to send those variables to PHP.

Either way, I highly recommend a function built into SQL like the LIMIT() function over updating the database with an extraneous query to give an entry a timestamp. I'm also unsure how that solution would work if multiple users were looking at the page at the same time.

Comment: One thing you should consider, jquery != php. They are not equivalents. You need both.

Comment: Well, actually it just needs to update on a page refresh, it will not need to actually update dynamically while the user sits on the page. Sorry if I made the question sound confusing in that sense.

Comment: If this is the case, why would you even think about jQuery? Unless I'm not understanding your original question, this is just "how to I get something from a database." Is your question how to use SQL `order by` and the `DESC` keyword?

Comment: @Nile Well, yes I would say so then. I just want to make sure I have this optimized when using php so that I do not have to make a ton of database calls. When using the echo command the content does not stay there on a refresh, which means I need to go through the hole db table again. I want to know if you can eliminate having to keep going through it each page load and rather then just echo, save it. Or is calling to the db for this not really that heavy on performance?

Comment: I don't think that's something to worry about in this case. I doubt it's that big a strain. If you don't want to use some type of database, you'd have to use javascript. If you're still worried you can try timing it using php microtime or sql benchmark.

Comment: @Nile Okay, I will do the way of simple going through the database and echo'ing it out. Is there a preferred way to do this that is the easiest?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking. I do prefer using PDO for running and executing queries and Smarty Template Engine for my templating engine to keep the queries and code from the results.

Comment: @Nile Oh, I'm just asking for what is the easiest way to use php to go through a database and display it. As in using a while loop and going through it

Comment: If you haven't already started using the original mysql api for php, I do suggest PDO and using $result->fetchAll() in a while loop. Otherwise, I suggest using mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc (according to which you want) in a while loop.

Comment: I've already been using the API, so I guess I would like to stick to that.

Comment: For the future, try PDO. Also remember to escape your strings. In PDO this is not required.

Comment: @nile: if you are using fetchall, why you need it inside a while loop?

Comment: @nile: PDO without prepared statement is as vulnerable as any other api. Plz mention prepared statement.

Comment: fetchAll() returns an array, so you'd want to loop through that array. you could also use fetch() to just go one by one, but in the end its the same except for timing/memory. and yes, that's also true. if you want to make your queries safe, prepare them and use the pdo styled variables.

Answer (score 0):

Add a timestamp to each row in db

whenever you read in jquery the rows keep the last timestamp in a variable

when you send request in jquery add the last timestamp and then filter using query `WHERE update_time > $jquery_timestamp`

using this way, only new info will be sent

Comment: Would simply storing the last displayed ID's work the same then? Or is there a specific reason to use timestamps?

Comment: What if a row gets deleted from previous fetching?

Comment: @Fogest it may work too :D, but usually I use timestamp when the id is not auto_increment

Comment: @itachi Good point. It may be a rare case of this happening, but I guess it's better to use the fool proof method then the easy way out.